# Commonly used construct to express the meaning of "let yourself to do something"

Tags: phrase-usage, idioms

This is a commonly used word to construct a phrase, which means to "let yourself to do something" or maybe "pamper yourself".

It is used like: "Today I decided to **verb** a hotdog."

*For an unknown reason I think about the word "fashion" or "spare", but these are obviously the wrong ones.*

There's a word that makes this phrase neat and succinct.

Please help me to find the word.

Comment: *Today I decided to **indulge in** [a treat]*.

Comment: Today I decided to **allow myself** a hot dog, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a single word that would replace the phrase you already have, but "*treat myself to*" would be more idiomatic:

> Today I treated myself to a hotdog.

For something you have never done before, the word "sample" could be used to similar effect:

> Today I decided to *sample* a hotdog.

It does sound slightly formal but is often used less formally to imply a little decadence, or that something is a 'treat'.

Comment: If I have had long and difficult day, I often decide to award myself a generous shot of my favourite single malt whisky.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey "award *myself*" is two words but yes that works too

Comment: Oh, in the end, I recalled what exactly I saw. It was this phrase: "do you fancy a drink?" The verb "fancy" is what was imprinted in my memory. But of course, it makes the question I asked the wrong question. Sorry about that. I selected your answer as the final one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KonstantinKozirev Okay - 'fancy' basically means *desire*, so it wouldn't fit your example.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the phrase "treat myself to" or "reward myself with" in this sentence.
I do not know a single word that encompasses the "let" portion of the question.

[Treat... to](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/treat+(someone+or+oneself)+to+(something))

> To pay for or provide something to someone or oneself as a special gift or treat.